# How do I solve this equation?

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

[image]

I can’t solve this equation.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    int n, result, sum, product;
    
    sum = 0; product = 1, result = 0;

    for (int n = 1; n <= 20; n++) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            sum = sum + ((i - n) / (i + n));
            product *= sum;
            result = sum + product;
        }
    }

    printf("result::%d",result);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: "I can’t do for loops." Is this an assignment restriction? You are using `for` loops.

Comment: You'll need to use some `double` variables, and cast to `double` before doing the divisions.

Comment: I don't get an error. The answer of the equation is not 0, but in the code I wrote, the answer is 0. We will write the code for the solution of the equation in the picture I sent.

Comment: If just one of the sums is `0`, so will the product be. Note: reset `sum = 0` *inside* the outer loop.

Comment: can u writing with new code ?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "I can’t do for loops.". Is using them forbidden or are you unable to implement a for loop with correct syntax?

Comment: i dont unable to implement a for loop with correct syntax. pls i need your help.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track, but note these problems:

- you should use `double` arithmetics for the computation and values, otherwise the result will be meaningless.
- you should initialize `sum` to `0` before the inner loop
- you should move the product outside the inner loop
- `n` is redefined in the outer `for` loop
- `result` is probably not needed.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    double product = 1.0;

    for (int n = 1; n <= 20; n++) {
        double sum = 0.0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            sum += (double)(i - n) / (double)(i + n);
        }
        product *= sum;
    }

    printf("result: %f\n", product);
    return 0;
}
```

The above direct translation of the formula outputs `-0.000000`. The explanation is simple: if you look at the formula, you will see that the first term of the product for `n=1` is sum for `i` from `1` to `1` of `(i - n) / (i + n)`, which is `(1 - 1) / (1 + 1)`, that is `0`. Multiplying that by any finite quantity will stay invariably null.

Hence the formula can be *solved* algebraically and produce a much simplified version. A good algorithm beats any brute force approach:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {    
    printf("result: 0\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: are you sure right?because the code results in zero.

Comment: @jack07taylor: Good point! if you look at the formula, you will see that the first term of the product (for `n=1`) is sum for `i` from `1` to `1` of `(i - n) / (i + n)`, which is `(1 - 1) / (1 + 1)`, that is `0`. Multiplying that by any finite quantity will stay invariably null. There must be an error in the formula :)

Comment: The result should not be 0.

Comment: @jack07taylor: What should the result be? Are you sure about the formula? Can you post the full problem description?

Comment: @jack07taylor: I am not sure what you mean

Comment: I said im not sure result be 0.Are you sure the result is 0?

Comment: @jack07taylor: If the formula is what shows on the picture, yes, the result is 0. Could this be a trick question? What is the context?

Comment: yes its in the picture.
I just started coding so I'm not sure I'm a beginner.

Comment: The result is a product. The first factor of the product is a sum with a single value `(i - n) / (i + n)` where both `i` and `n` have the value `1`. Hence this factor is `0`. It does not matter what the other factors evaluate to, the result is `0`. No coding needed. QED.